# Microsoft Access: Monthly income at a glance, comparing past few years

Tags: ms-access

I want to build a query to show income for each month of the year, for the past three years, but with each year as a field. This way, I can see annual income for the past three years, while also comparing same months each year at a glance.

I'm not sure if that was clear, but it's simple to see visually. So here is the table I have,
[image: LessonPayT]

And from this, I'd like this query(I entered data in excel for screenshot):
[image: MonthlyIncomeQ]

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text table, not image.

Comment: Did you try the CROSSTAB query wizard? Extract year and month values from PayDate and use those in the CROSSTAB design..

Comment: For a start, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Comment: Thank you! Yes, Crosstab query wizard did the trick. And I'll take note to include date as text... Are there a rulebook that explains how to do that?

Comment: Review https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: in access the easiest way to format your tables and queries as text is by exporting them to a file as text and then cutting and pasting into stack overflow.

Comment: AFAIK, simple copy/paste text does not retain columnar structure. Can copy/paste from Access or Excel and get same result as from text file. Have to type in formatting characters or use a tool like https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables